# Cannot convert object to string

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am unsure why this wont work. I have a datagrid and I want to create a selection based on each Item that would navigate me to the next part of the application

```
    private void MedicationDatagrid_SelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedMedication = MedicationData.RetrieveMedicationByBarcode(MedicationDatagrid.SelectedItem, string.Empty, 0);

    }
```

Comment: `MedicationDatagrid.SelectedItem.ToString()`?

Comment: what is the signature of `MedicationData.RetrieveMedicationByBarcode` ?

Answer (score 3):

Making the ***assumption*** that `SelectedMedication` is a `string`, then this:

```
SelectedMedication = MedicationData.RetrieveMedicationByBarcode(
    MedicationDatagrid.SelectedItem,
    string.Empty,
    0) as string;
```

would conceivably work. However, we have ***no idea*** what's returned from `RetrieveMedicationByBarcode` so you may need to `override` the `ToString()` method on that type for this to work as you would expect.

However, it's also possible the problem is `MedicationDatagrid.SelectedItem` and the method is expecting a `string` as the first parameter. If that's the case then this:

```
SelectedMedication = MedicationData.RetrieveMedicationByBarcode(
    MedicationDatagrid.SelectedItem as string,
    string.Empty,
    0);
```

would conceivably fix your issue.